# How am I supposed to map a datetime json string property into the TypeScript date type?

Tags: angular

Here is the setup that I am having trouble with

Raw json from API

```
{
  "messageContent": "string",
  "dateTimeSent": "2020-07-02T20:43:52.814Z",
  "isMessageRead": true
}
```

The raw json is put in as a message here in my mapper, and I am a bit lost from here

```
  mapMessage(message)
  {
    let mappedMessage = new Message;

    mappedMessage.messageContent = message.messageContent;
    mappedMessage.dateTimeSent = message.dateTimeSent //This is not working here
    mappedMessage.isMessageRead = message.isMessageRead;

    return mappedMessage;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap the raw date in a new Date() function.

e.g.

```
mappedMessage.dateTimeSent = new Date(message.dateTimeSent);
```